# Java to Exe Files

Tags: java, jar, exe, libraries, jsmooth

I'm having a hard time figuring how to convert **jar files with its libraries** into an `.exe file`.
I know how to convert jar files(ONLY) to an .exe file using `JSmooth` but I don't know how to add its libraries in it.

What I'm trying to accomplish is that I wanna execute the file without having the `\lib` and `jar file(s)` in the location of `.exe file`. I want the `.exe file` to be independent.

'Cause The scenario I've encountered was that I have this `.jar file`, the `lib` folder, and the `.exe file` in the same location. When I try to execute the `.exe file` nothing's wrong, it worked well. When I try to move away the `.exe file` from the `jar file` and the `\lib`. It won't worked anymore. Is there a way that I can just delete the jar and the lib folder but leaving the `.exe file` working just fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your exe from anywhere depending you have the jars in your classpath. You can make use of environment variable to set the class path and simply put this in your exe:

For windows:

```
java -classpath .;local.jar MainClass
```

For unix/linux:

```
   java -classpath .:local.jar MainClass
```

Comment: just a side note : While specifying your jars use `;` for windows systems and `:` in linux based systems.

Comment: Based on the answer given, I assumed that there is no way wherein I can just copy the .exe file alone, meaning with the \lib and jar file, then transfer it to another pc and execute it without getting any error, am I right?